# PHP - How can I generate this file structure using recursion?

Tags: php, recursion, file-structure

I need to generate a file structure like this:

- If I have an ID that have the value of 5, the file structure will be "files/5/id_5/"
- If I have an ID that have the value of 32, the file structure will be "files/3/2/id_32/"
- If I have an ID that have the value of 1000, the file structure will be "files/1/0/0/0/id_1000/"

Any ideas on how to do this?

Best Regards,

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried? This isn't a homework site.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck in implementing this? Why does it have to use recursion? A loop will do just fine here. In fact, this can be done using trivial string manipulation without any loops at all.

Comment: You seems to be an old stackoverflow member how can you post such questions? ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data   = '1000';
$format = 'files/'.implode('/',str_split($data)).'/id_'.$data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code.

### [DEMO](http://codepad.org/OA2PWaqY)

```
<?php 
$str = "10";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
$id = '';
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($arr1) ; $i++) {
    $id .= "/".$arr1[$i];
}
$front = "files";
$tail = "/id_".$str;
echo $front . $id . $tail ;
?>
```

`implode()` can be used also instead for loop.